# Using generics to implement a common method in an abstract class

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have this hierarchy:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Cloneable {
    ...
    public AbstractEntity clone() {
        Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
        AbstractEntity cloned = cloner.deepClone(this);
        return cloned;
    }
}

public class EntityA extends AbstractEntity {
    ...
}
```

This works fine, I can do:

```
EntityA e1 = new EntityA();
EntityA e2 = (EntityA) e1.clone();
```

but I have to do a manual typecast.
Is there a way to use java Generics in order to have the **clone()** method return the actual type of the subclass?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think generics are needed.  You can declare a clone() method in the abstract class, and override it to return a subclass in the subclass.

```
package inheritance;

public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    public abstract AbstractEntity clone();
}


package inheritance;

public class ClassA extends AbstractEntity {

    @Override
    public ClassA clone() { return null; }

}


package inheritance;

public class Driver {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        ClassA b = a.clone();
        System.out.println("all done");
    }

}
```

Isn't that what you wanted to do?

Comment: The clone behavior is not type-specific, so he wants to avoid a bunch of unnecessary overrides.

Comment: I would think this would be less trouble, and cleaner, than using generics; hopefully the OP will let us know if this fits his case.  If the cloning behavior is not type-specific, there's no reason he can't have the subclass invoke the superclass method; then he has common cloning code and does not have to cast his result, AND he doesn't have the strange-looking class that he would end up with using generics, nor the possibility of the "EvilEntity" mentioned in the existing generics-based answer.  The cost is having a method in each subclass to invoke the super and return the right type.

Comment: I agree. Generics are supposed to be about type-safety, not less typing, so this approach actually makes a lot of sense.

Comment: you both are right, erickson and rcook: yes, I wanted to avoid overrides, and yes I wanted a complete type safety without awkward artifacts. I understand I can't achieve both, so the best solution is this.

Answer (score 6):

The closest I can think of would be something like:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<T extends AbstractEntity<T>> 
    implements Cloneable {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T clone() {
        Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
        T cloned = (T) cloner.deepClone(this);
        return cloned;
    }    
}

public class EntityA extends AbstractEntity<EntityA> { 
    ...
}

public class EntityB extends AbstractEntity<EntityB> { 
    ...
}
```

It's not entirely safe: you could write:

```
public class EvilClass extends AbstractEntity<EntityA> { 
    ...
}
```

... but whether or not that's important to you depends on your use case.

Comment: hmm... That's what I was afraid of: in order to have a reference to the type of the class itself I must declare it as "a class of a class of the same class" ;-)
Nice trick, by the way, It's useful for me to better learn Java. Thank you.